# Attribute name "webkitdirectory" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have one spring boot web app and I get the following exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "webkitdirectory" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

for one of the thymeleaf HTML templates that looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="form-path">
            <label for="formControlProjectPath">File input</label>
            <input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory id="formControlProjectPath" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do in order to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using older version of `thymeleaf`, you must write XML-valid `HTML` code.

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory="webkitdirectory" mozdirectory="mozdirectory" msdirectory= "msdirectory" odirectory="odirectory" directory="directory" id="formControlProjectPath" />
```

But starting `thymeleaf 3.0` there is no need to write XML-valid `HTML` code.

So if you have option to upgrade, I encourage you to update to version 3.0

here is [thymeleaf 3 migration docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html).